# Given two strings, how do I assign the shorter string to one variable and the longer string to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am learning python and would like to know if there is a *pythonic* way of doing this. Of course I can do an

```
if len(a) > len(b) :
  (x,y) = (b,a)
```

and so on. But this seems a bit verbose. Is there a more beautiful way to do this in python?

Comment: @user3483203 have to sort by length.

Comment: If you're looking for a clever way you can sort, but your way now is perfectly fine

Comment: @user3483203 but I would need the else and so on. Kinda verbose I think. And do you know why people are downvoting this like hell? :D

Comment: @Can'tTell I think that the downvotes are a sort of *"I think it's primarly opinion-based, but not worth a flag"*, even if I think it's an interesting question. BTW you actually have a positive score!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorting seems a bit overkill. You can do it in one line just with `if`.

```
x,y = (a,b) if len(a) < len(b) else (b,a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To explain more, it was not the length that bothered me, but the verbosity of expressing something so simple.

Comment: @MBo I did in the title. In the code I have not, but I have said 'and so on'. I was too lazy to write the else part

Comment: OK, removing my comment. But author should be more careful :)

Answer (score 2):

```
x = min(a, b, key=len)
y = max(a, b, key=len)
```

Repetition, but intention is clear.

### Edit:

Removed parentheses that makes tuples out of `a` and `b` since `min` and `max` takes in variable number of arguments.

Comment: using `sort` with multiple assignment would be better. You run the comparisons only once like that.

Comment: I think this is the most expressive way to do what is stated in the title. "Assign shorter to one and the longer to another". The mission here isn't to deal with more than 2 variables and it would make sense to do it in two steps.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I agree that sorting approach generalizes to larger collection more elegantly. Performance wise, not sure if there is going to be significant difference since collection is small. The accepted solution is essentially a special case of sorting 2 items and, depending on individual preferences, more readable. My intention was to offer an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Found one way.

```
(x,y) = sorted([a,b], key = len)
```

Comment: I prefer your original way.

Comment: @khelwood but it requires 4 lines though

Comment: Don't get caught up in one-linerness, your code is perfectly readable now

Comment: @Can'tTell If you need one liner, this will work: `if len(a) > len(b) :(x,y) = (b,a)`. No two lines ;)

Comment: @Can'tTell if the number of lines influence a *beautiful* code, you should define what you mean with *beautiful*

Comment: @Gsk I did not mean that as a general rule, but the original didn't seem very python like to me. But if you look at khelwood's answer you will see what I meant.

Comment: Have you measure the execution time?. using `if` taking less time than using `sorted`. (ie, `0.007247173540780684` while using `if` and `0.012815168972169048` while using `sorted` in my machine)

Answer (score 1):

Use *min(n1, n2, n3, ...)*

```
>>> n1 = "abcdefghijkl"
>>> n2 = "abc"
>>> min((n1,n2), key=len)
'abc'
>>> max((n1,n2), key=len)
'abcdefghijkl'
```

Comment: `min('111', '0000')` will return `'0000'`.  This doesn't do what you think it does.  You *can* however give `len` as a key to `min`

Comment: @user3483203 Thanks just fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use sequence unpacking with `min` / `max`. This is still O(*n*) complexity, albeit a 2-pass solution, which doesn't involve creating an intermediary `list` or `tuple` of strings.

```
a = 'hello'
b = 'test'

x, y = (func(a, b, key=len) for func in (min, max))

print(x, y, sep='\n')

# test
# hello
```

Here's a functional version:

```
from operator import methodcaller

x, y = map(methodcaller('__call__', a, b, key=len), (min, max))
```

Comment: A whole lot of pythonism here.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems really *opinion-based*, and for this reason I think we should define *beautiful* referring to the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), in particular:

> Flat is better than nested.
>   Sparse is better than dense.
>   Readability counts.

For these reasons, I think that your approach:

```
if len(a) > len(b) :
    (x,y) = (b,a)
else:
    (x,y) = (a,b)
```

is the **best one**.

Answer (score 1):

Just a demo how dict can also be used

Solution 1:

```
a = [3]
b = [2,3 ]

_bool = len(a)<len(b)

d = { True : a, False : b}

x = d[_bool]
y = d[not _bool]


print(x, y)
```

Using Lists:

Solution 2:

```
x, y = [[a, b], [b, a]][len(a) > len(b)]
```

Although my preferred approach is

```
x, y = sorted([a, b], key=len)
```